# Is it possible to set proportional grid columns based on content?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

Using either Flexbox or CSS Grid, is it possible to size my columns based on the contents of one of the columns?

## Here’s What I Want:

I have 2 columns, a **main** and a **side**.

```
|------------------------container--------------------------|
|                                                           |
||----------------------------------------|----------------||
||               main                     |      side      ||
||----------------------------------------|----------------||
|                                                           |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
```

I want the **side** to be automatically sized based on its content, and I want the **main** to be twice as wide as the **side**, at a minimum. It can grow bigger, but no smaller.

As the container increases, the **main** will grow at the same rate, while the **side** remains its auto width.

```
|--------------------------container increases----------------------|
|                                                                   |
||------------------------------------------------|----------------||
||                   main increases               |      side      ||
||------------------------------------------------|----------------||
|                                                                   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The container can shrink down to 3 times as big as the **side**, at which point the **main** will be twice as wide as the **side**. I want this to be the breakpoint.

```
|--------------------container----------------------|
|                                                   |
||--------------------------------|----------------||
||               main             |      side      ||
||--------------------------------|----------------||
|                                                   |
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

If the container shrinks any more, I want the columns to stack, where both columns are now 100% width:

```
|--------------------container--------------------|
|                                                 |
||-----------------------------------------------||
||               main                            ||
||-----------------------------------------------||
||-----------------------------------------------||
||                           side                ||
||-----------------------------------------------||
|                                                 |
|-------------------------------------------------|
```

## Here’s What I’ve Tried:

I tried doing this with Flexbox and with Grid, but I couldn’t get the main column to determine its size based on the side column.

```
.container-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto; /* works, but doesn’t wrap when left column gets too small */
  /* I also tried the repeat() syntax, but that only worked for similarly-sized columns */
}
```

```
.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.main { flex: 2; } .side { flex: 1; } /* same problem, doesn’t wrap */
.main ( flex: 0 1 auto; } .side { flex: 0 0 auto; } /* wraps columns too early, any time main is smaller than intrinsic width */
```

The only solution I’ve tried that works is knowing the fixed width of the side column (which I would have to predict without knowing its content), and then using a media query at 3 times its width. And of course, the media query only works on window width, not container width, so I would have to calculate the media query using any parent elements of the container.

```
.container-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 15em;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 45em) {
  .container-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution, using Flexbox, where you use a *flex-grow* value being very much bigger on `main` than on `side`.

With this, the `side` will fill parent when wrapped, and when on wide screen, with the so much higher value on the `main`, the *flex-growth* on `side` will practically be none.

Combined with a `min-width` on the `main` being twice the size of the `side`, it will wrap before it gets smaller, and for that we can use percent as that is based on parent's width.

So in this case twice the size on `main` will be 2/3 of parent, 66.666%.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/51vr4jqd/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main {
  flex: 10000;
  min-width: 66.666%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.side {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: lightgreen;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-flex">

  <div class="main">
    <span>Fill remain, min. twice the "side"</span>
  </div>

  <div class="side">
    <span>Take content size</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Seems to me a perfect solution ....  I don't understand your comment *the closest I can come*

Comment: @vals Thanks ... will change that part, as when you say it like that it sounds strange :)

Comment: @vals I imagine the “closest I can come” part because it seems a little hacky: setting the flex-grow to an arbitrarily large number. But it looks like it might work, so I’m willing to give it a shot.

Comment: @chharvey Yes, that is correct. And the reason is the need of setting `flex-grow` to `1` on the `side`, or else it won't fill parent when wrapped, but when unwrapped, the `flex-grow` on `main` need to be big enough so when the space left, after content being reduced, is calculated, the `main` has to take _all_, or else the `side` will grow some as well. So technically `side` will get 1/10001 of the space left and `main` gets 10000/10001, which were why I said _the closest_ :)

Comment: @LGSon - Your logic is perfectly sound; I just don't typically think that way when writing CSS. There is usually a property or value in CSS that does exactly what I want… most of the time. That’s why I called your method a bit “hacky.” But it solves the problem, so I’m marking it as the solution until a better one comes along! (FTR, I used 999999 because it’s higher and easier to type.)

Comment: Oooh, I just now realized you can use `flex: 999999 0 66.666%;` instead of `min-width`, so that way this solution can also work for `flex-direction: column;`.

Comment: @chharvey Technically, when setting an _initial_ `flex-basis` combined with `flex-shrink` set to zero, yes, though test if thoroughly cross browsers, as in some situations nested flex element using `flex-basis` with percent not always work, hence `width` or `min-width` can be needed.

Comment: @chharvey Also note, using percent for an element's `height` might be troublesome since elements doesn't pick percentage based `height` in the same way as it does with `width`, and this is because of elements normal default `height` value is `auto` and for `width` it is `100%`.